# can we change the database for Crafter cms to sql server

Tags: sql-server, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I need to know if I can change the database of crafter cms from no sql to sql server database ?

Comment: Maybe you should check with the vendor?

Comment: It is open-source so theoretically you can interface it to whatever backend you desire - just write some code.

Comment: I Googled Crafter CMS (as I had never heard of it), and they answer this question in their own [Documentation](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/faq/index.html?highlight=database#do-i-need-to-connect-crafter-cms-to-a-database): *"Crafter Studio embeds and manages its own database. Crafter Social and Crafter Profile leverage MongoDB. These are optional components."*

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the System requirements and searching through their documentation I would hazard a guess that they do not support SQL Server and this would likely be more of a custom modification you would need to undertake if you have the required skills.

According to Crafter's documentation, the requirements are for Mongo DB 3 which is included with the base installation of the product.

Unless the vendor clearly specifies they support the DB Engine I would strongly suggest against moving away from the already-in-place database engine.

Documetation I'm making reference to can be found here https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/system-administrators/index.html